# What is the alternative pinescript Nz function in Ninjascript?

Tags: c#, pine-script

I'm attempting to translate a Pine Script code snippet into NinjaScript. The original code defines a nonLagEMA function and computes a nonLagOscillator value. However, when I debug my NinjaScript code, the nonLagOscillator consistently returns NaN (Not-a-Number).

Here's the original Pine Script code:

```
nonLagEMA(src, length) =>
    alpha = 2 / (length + 1)
    ema = 0.0
    ema := alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * nz(ema[1])
    ema

nonLagOscillator = 100 * (close - nonLagEMA(close, fastPeriod)) / nonLagEMA(close, fastPeriod)
```

And here's my NinjaScript implementation so far:

```
//       Define the Non-Lag Exponential Moving Average indicator
        public double NonLagEMA(ISeries<double> src, int length)
        {
            alpha[0] = 2 / (length + 1);
            
            ema[0] = 0.0;
            
            ema[0] = alpha[0] * src[0] + (1 - alpha[0]) * ema[1];

            return ema[0];
            
        }

protected override void OnBarUpdate()
        {
            //Add your custom indicator logic here.
            
            if (CurrentBars[0] < 1)
                return;
            
            nonLagOscillator[0] = 100 * (Close[0] - NonLagEMA(Close, fast_period)) / NonLagEMA(Close, fast_period);
    
            Print("nonLagOscillator:" + nonLagOscillator[0]);

            histogramPlot[0] = nonLagOscillator[0];
            
            
        }
```

Despite my efforts, the NinjaScript version produces NaN for nonLagOscillator. I've ensured that the input data and parameters match between the Pine Script and NinjaScript versions.

Could someone please assist in identifying what might be causing the NaN output in the NinjaScript version?

Answer (score 0):

The calculation of the NonLagEMA function corresponds exactly to the EMA indicator included in NinjaTrader. Accordingly, you can simply use EMA(Period). The rest is fine, here is an executable indicator:

```
#pragma warning disable CS0436

using NinjaTrader.Gui;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.Indicators.Other
{
    [CategoryOrder("Settings", 0)]

    public class EMAOSC : Indicator
    {
        private EMA _ema;

        [NinjaScriptProperty]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Custom.Resource),
                 Name = "Period",
                 GroupName = "Settings",
                 Order = 0)]
        public int Period { get; set; }

        protected override void OnStateChange()
        {
            if (State == State.SetDefaults)
            {
                Description = @"EMA-Oscillator";
                Name = "EMAOSC";
                Calculate = Calculate.OnPriceChange;
                IsOverlay = false;
                IsSuspendedWhileInactive = true;

                Period = 20;

                AddPlot(Brushes.Goldenrod, Name);
            }
            else if (State == State.DataLoaded)
            {
                _ema = EMA(Period);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnBarUpdate()
        {
            Value[0] = 100 * (Input[0] - _ema[0]) / _ema[0];
        }
    }
}

#pragma warning restore CS0436
```